# Delete a key from an associative array

Tags: javascript, object

Consider `var person=JSON.parse('{"name":"Alice","id",1234}')`.

How do I remove a key from the variable person? For example, how do I remove "name" completely, so that `person` becomes `{"id":1234}`?

Comment: This is not an associative array.  It is an object literal.  There is no `length` property like with an array (unless of course you define one).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I remove objects from a javascript associative array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/346021/how-do-i-remove-objects-from-a-javascript-associative-array)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try `delete person["name"]`.

Notice that `delete` will only set it as undefined, which will then not be reflected correctly in the length of the array.

If you know the key you should use splice i.e.

`myArray.splice(key, 1);`