# Javascript - possible to remove element of an associative array

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to remove an element of a Javascript associative array (i.e., set back to native undefined)?

When I tried simply `alert(array['knownKey']); array['knownKey']=undefined; alert(array['knownKey']);` ... the second alert produced the literal undefined... whereas, the first alert returned nothing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delete a key from an associative array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754777/delete-a-key-from-an-associative-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To actually delete an element, use

```
delete array['knownkey'];
```

Comment: very helpful coming from php dev perspective -  lack of `unset()`