# Find a hyperlinked text and hide

Tags: jquery

I have this code on my site to find a specific hyperlinked text and hide, but this is removing the hyperlinks on all other texts, i do not want to do that,can someone tell me how do hide the specific text only without removing the hyper link on others?

this is my code

```
$('.myname').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    $(this).text(text.replace('rob-blank', ''));
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/6v5K2/1/)

thanks

Comment: Can you provide the HTML markup and a jsFiddle, please?

Comment: what exactly is $('.myname') element?

Comment: @MelanciaUK i have added the jsfiddle, but my code is not working this time on it

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you only want to grab a particular hyperlink. For this you will need a more particular selector; your selector will grab every tag with the class 'myname', which is likely too general for your purpose.

Try applying an id to the link you want to delete, and then use the id selector,

```
$('#<your id>').each(...);
```

instead.

Comment: an .each() function on a group selected by id is kinda funny :)

Comment: Yeah, but it attaches a scope to the element, which is kind of convenient in this case (in my opinion)

Comment: No it is not. Further more, if you have more than one element with this ID on the page, you'll have more other problems. If not, there is absolutely no reason to use ".each()" on an array that only have 1 element in it. None.

Answer (score 0):

Check the <kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ronency/Ujq72/1/)</kbd>

Given this HTML

```
<a>Lorem</a><br />
<a>Ipsum</a><br />
<a>Dolor</a><br />
<a>Sit</a><br />
<a>Amet</a><br />
```

You could just do this:

```
$('a').each(function(){
    var current = $(this);
    if(current.text() == 'Dolor'){
        current.css('color', 'red'); // or anything else you want to do with this element...
    }
});
```

Comment: just the text? or the entire hyperlink that contain a specific text?

Comment: i have a demo here, but this code is not working now for some reason http://jsfiddle.net/6v5K2/1/

Comment: It's not working because the text you're trying to modify is the <a>'s text, and not the div's text. Can you explain what is it that you are Trying to do? I think that the "solution" you are trying to apply is wrong in the first place...

Comment: the code actually works on my site..i have some hyperlinked text on my page and it is almost impossible to remove them without using jquery. i need to hide that text from appearing on my page.

Comment: In my answer, you can replace the current.css(...) with current.remove();
If you want to remove the element without using jQuery, check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5933157/how-to-remove-an-html-element-using-javascript