# How do I remove an HTML element from a webpage using javascript? (Trying to make a chrome extension)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, google-chrome-extension

So now...
[I am trying to remove the div class 'box' based on the product having the title 'iPhone' in the string in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTpBF.png)

Comment: What code are you using to do the delete?

Comment: Ill edit my post in a sec

Comment: It's seem duplicated here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5933157/how-to-remove-an-html-element-using-javascript

Comment: Yea I tried using his implementation but I still couldn't get anything from the website to be deleted

Comment: Take a look at https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9602022/chrome-extension-retrieving-gmails-original-message

Comment: you must include the problem and code in the question itself

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [:contains selector](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/), you can use the following code.

```
$("p:contains('iPhone')").closest("div.box").remove();
```

`p:contains('iPhone')` will get all `<p>` which contains iPhone in it text, while `closest("div.box")` will get the first `div` with class `box`, then `remove` will remove the `div` as well as everything inside it.