# How to destory object iterated in foreach loop

Tags: javascript

I am detecting whether the mousepointer is within an `ellipse` that I have drawn in P5.js. When the mouse is in contact with the `ellipse` it should be deleted. I can achieve this by iterating over the array that stores the ellipses `locations`, checking if the mouse pointer is close enough to them to be warranted as inside by accessing the width `element.w`. This is a way to do it with a simple for loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++){
    var d = dist(mouseX, mouseY, locations[i].x, locations[i].y);
    if(d <= locations[i].w){
        locations.splice(i,1);
    }
}
```

I am wondering what the `forEach` loop way to do this would be. I premuse it would be something like the below code, but how do you actually destroy the element?

```
locations.forEach(function(element) {
    var d = dist(mouseX, mouseY, element.x, element.y);
    if(d <= element.w){
        //Destoy the element??? How do you do that????
    }                   
});
```

Comment: locations.forEach(function(element, i) { look you can an index to foreach https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/forEach and make a splice as demo behind

Comment: check the callback signature https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach function callback(currentValue, index, array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this if you don't want to deal with browser compatibility issues for `.remove()`

```
function removeDummy() {
    var elem = document.getElementById('dummy');
    elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
    return false;
}
```

**The snippet is from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/5933167/4724167.**

Answer (score 1):

use filter function of Array, def variable preserve new array

Answer (score 0):

Try using `element.remove()`, but this has cross-browser compatibility issues.