# HTML button tag removal from backend

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have created a button dynamically in JavaScript and i am deleting the same when user clicks X symbol on it..
I am setting style.display=none to achieve this but the problem is in HTML there is space in it even after deleting the button. How can i delete the button without any space in HTML.

```
 var x = document.getElementById(id);
 x.style.display='none';
```

Comment: could your please add all the html and javascript example

Comment: @G.aziz, html and js is too big to add it here .. could you please let me know how to remove button dynamically ..

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you Google remove HTML element in javascript the first thing you see is this: [How to remove an HTML element using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5933157/how-to-remove-an-html-element-using-javascript/17560385)

and it works, but I'll pitch in my 2 cents anyways since that one uses parentElement, which is kinda outdated.

There's a .remove() method in javascript that lets you remove an html element.
It's as simple as:

```
var x  = document.querySelector("#id");
x.remove();
```

but I doubt that will solve your issue, you might want to remove the parent element if it has a margin or padding like so:

```
var x  = document.querySelector("#id");
x.parentElement.remove();
```

cheers

Comment: thanks for the issue ... i have tried with that aswell but still its not solving the issue.

Answer (score -1):

try it if u want to change the css

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#id").css('display', 'none');
</script>
```

or use it for add or remove the class. change the add to remove if want remove the class

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("submit").classList.add('disabled'); 
</script>
```

Comment: They haven't stated that they are using jquery, so your first solution won't work