# Remove and add new HTML-Tags

Tags: javascript, php, html

Is there a way in PHP or Javascript to delete html tags and add new ones?

For example:
I have a contact form. If the user enters the correct values and clicks on "send", then all HTML tags for the contact form should be deleted, so that the contact form disappears.
After that, for example, a div-tag should be inserted with the text "Your mail was sent successfully. I will get back to you soon. Thanks a lot".

So, this code:

```
......

<form action="php/test.php" method="post" novalidate="">
 <div class="row">
   <div class="column width-5 offset">
        <input type="text" name="lname" class="form-lname form-element large" placeholder="Name" tabindex="1">
     </div>
  <div class="column width-5 offset">
   <input type="email" name="email" class="form-email form-element large" placeholder="E-Mail-*" tabindex="2" required="">
     </div>
</div>
  </form>
......
```

is to be changed to this code after you click on "send". 
`<div>Your mail was sent successfully. I will get back to you soon. Thanks a lot<div>` 
Is it possible with php or javascript to replace the html tags? Or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: So the first thing to point out is you are doing a form submit, which is going to cause the page to transfer to a new page; `test.php`.  Unless you are performing some javascript logic to prevent that.

Comment: Better option will be to hide and show divs. Hide form on submit button and show success div with your mail success content.

Comment: please provide the entire code. I can't see the button in charge of submitting the form nor the Javascript in charge of doing so. We only see Html

Comment: There are so many examples here on SO, do any of them help?  I searched for "javascript remove element", there are thousands of answers with code you can use.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove an HTML element using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5933157/how-to-remove-an-html-element-using-javascript)

Comment: Okay, maybe I asked my question poorly. Because I actually want to avoid javascript. Because there are people who have javascript turned it off or don't allow it. That's why I wanted to know if I can delete html tags with PHP or if I have to work with javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several options here (
I would recommend second option).

If you want to stay on same page and hide it with javascript:

```
<p>If you click on the "Hide" button, I will disappear.</p>

 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#hide").click(function(){
    $("p").hide();
  });
  $("#show").click(function(){
    $("p").show();
  });
});
```

Second option is PHP.
You should make a new page with message:

Your mail was sent successfully. I will get back to you soon. Thanks a lot...

You just need to change `header('Location: success.php');` after inserting your query.

hope this was helpful. :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As commented by me above (last comment). I did ask the question a bit badly. I actually want to avoid javascript for it, if the user has javascript turned off. 
Okay, then I guess I have to take the second option. Thank you.