# How do you remove a element by id?

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I am trying to get a few buttons to work but all the other things I found didnt work here it is

```
document.getElementById("Element").remove();
```

isnt working

```
<button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="reset()">Reset</button>
```

Error:

```
script.js:30 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of null
at reset (script.js:30)
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:14)
```

Im sorry if this is formatted weird but I am new to this.

Comment: Does the element to be removed have `id="Element"`?

Comment: The button doesn't have any id. You need to give it the correct id to be able to remove it.

Comment: Can you post full code with elements having id `Element`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: If you need to remove the button with id "Element" then the button need to have a id="Element " attribute, but the example given doesn't have the id attribute.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove an HTML element using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5933157/how-to-remove-an-html-element-using-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
<button id="reset-button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="reset()">Reset</button>
```

And you can remove the button via

```
document.getElementById("reset-button").remove();
```

Answer (score 2):

I didn't get what you are trying to do, I am assuming you are trying to remove the button.

you are trying to get button by element id but there is no id attribute in the button tag,
it should look like something like below

```
document.getElementById("id_name").remove();

<button id="id_name" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="reset()">Reset</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

The element you want to remove needs to have `id="Element"`.

For example if you want to remove a div it would look like:

```
<div id="Element"> Div to remove </div>
```

then your script:

```
function reset() {
  document.getElementById("Element").remove();
}
```

will work for the button:

```
<button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="reset()">Reset</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just give the id name to your button with the same name you're giving in remove.

```
document.getElementById("Element").remove();
<button id="Element" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="reset()">Reset</button>
```