# Remove <p> elements on click

Tags: javascript

I have this script:

```
var text = ["Ground Beef", "Spaghetti", "Tomatoes", "Onions", "Cheese"];
text.forEach(function(el) {
    var div = document.createElement("p");
    div.className = "list";
    div.innerHTML = el;
    document.body.appendChild(div);
});
```

Please let me know how to add on click function to delete each for this elements Ground Beef ....

Comment: Why is the name of the variable `div` when it stores a paragraph?

Comment: `EventTarget.addEventListener()`, `ChildNode.remove()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove an HTML element using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5933157/how-to-remove-an-html-element-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You could assign click event via `onclick` attribute. Then remove the element via `e.target`

```js
var text = ["Ground Beef", "Spaghetti", "Tomatoes", "Onions", "Cheese"];
text.forEach(function(el) {
    var div = document.createElement("p");
    div.className = "list";
    div.innerHTML = el;
    div.onclick = remover
    document.body.appendChild(div);
});


function remover(e){
  e.target.remove()
}
```