# splicing specific value in array of array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an associative array stored in another associative array. I know how to splice a specific value in just a regular array as such:

```
arr.splice(arr.indexOf('specific'), 1);
```

I was wondering how one could splice an array such as this:

```
arr['hello']['world']
```

**EDIT** Would this shorten `hello['world']['continent']`

```
var hello = {};
            hello['world'] = {};
            hello['world']['continent'] = "country";
            delete hello['world']['continent'];
            alert(hello['world']['continent'])
```

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have "associative" arrays.

Comment: What are `hello` and `world`?  What does `arr` look like?  What do you want it to look like?

Comment: `arr['hello']['world']` can also be accessed as `arr.hello.world`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to just just use the delete keyword.

```
delete arr["hello"]["world"]
```

[How do I remove objects from a javascript associative array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/346021/how-do-i-remove-objects-from-a-javascript-associative-array)

Edit, based on other comments:

For the sake of readability, you can also do:

```
delete arr.hello.world
```

Since we are really just talking about objects, and not traditional arrays, there is no array length. You can however delete a key from an object.

Comment: would this shorten the array though?

Comment: It would remove the world object all together. So, it would shorten arr["hello"]

Comment: wouldn't it just make it undefined...im pretty sure

Comment: I agree with Praneet Sharma.  delete sets an item undefined while splice actually "shortens".

Comment: @esnyder: JavaScript doesn't have "associative" arrays.  If the key is `"hello"`, that means `arr` is an object, not an array, so it doesn't have a length (so "shorten" doesn't make sense here).

Comment: `delete` used on an array will leave a space with `undefined`, but used on an object, it will remove the property.

Comment: I was thinking of the length more in the context of listing the keys of the object. In that case I believe it would shorten the list of keys.

Comment: @Rocket The reason I put "shortens" in those quotes is exactly what you're suggesting...  "shortens" doesn't make sense (exactly as you said).  That's what I was trying to communicate. :)

Answer (score 1):

**JavaScript does not have associative arrays.**

Use objects:

```
var x = {
  a : 1,
  b : 2,
  c : {
     a : []
  }
}

delete x.c.a;
```

Answer (score 0):

An "associative array" in javascript isn't actually an array, it's just an object that has properties set on it. `Foo["Bar"]` is the same thing as `Foo.Bar`. So you can't really talk about slicing or length here.