# console.log(array) returns empty, but console.log(array.length) doesn't return 0

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following javascript

```
var filtered = [];

$('#footballCheck').on('change', function() {
  if ($('#footballCheck').is(':checked')) {
    for (var i = 0; i < fa_names.length; i++) {
      if (fa_names[i]["facility_activity"].toLowerCase().indexOf("football") >= 0) {
        filtered.push(fa_names[i]);
      }
    }

    filtered.sort(SortByName);
    $('#mCSB_1_container').empty(".facility-name");
    for (var k = 0; k < filtered.length; k++) {
      $('#mCSB_1_container').append('<div class="row facility-name">\
                                             <button class="btn btn-default btn-fill btn-menu" date-name="' + filtered[k]["facility_name"] + '">' + filtered[k]["facility_name"] + '</button></div>');
      $('#facilities-body').mCustomScrollbar("update");
    }
  } else {
    for (var j = 0; j < filtered.length; j++) {
      if (filtered[j]["facility_activity"].toLowerCase().indexOf("football") >= 0) {
        delete filtered[j];
      }
    }
    console.log(filtered);
    console.log(filtered.length);
    if (filtered.length > 0) {
      filtered.sort(SortByName);
      $('#mCSB_1_container').empty(".facility-name");
      for (var k = 0; k < filtered.length; k++) {
        $('#mCSB_1_container').append('<div class="row facility-name">\
                                                 <button class="btn btn-default btn-fill btn-menu" date-name="' + filtered[k]["facility_name"] + '">' + filtered[k]["facility_name"] + '</button></div>');
        $('#facilities-body').mCustomScrollbar("update");
      }
    } else {
      $('#mCSB_1_container').empty(".facility-name");
      for (k = 0; k < fa_names.length; k++) {
        $('#mCSB_1_container').append('<div class="row facility-name">\
                                                 <button class="btn btn-default btn-fill btn-menu" date-name="' + fa_names[k]["facility_name"] + '">' + fa_names[k]["facility_name"] + '</button></div>');
        $('#facilities-body').mCustomScrollbar("update");
      }
    }
  }
});
```

that should do the following:

- If the checkbox is checked, go through another array and push all objects whose key value "facility_activity" contains "football" to the `filtered` array
- If it is unchecked, then remove all objects from `filtered` array whose key value "facility_activity" contains "football"
- If it is unchecked and its length is > 0 (meaning that there are still filtered objects) print those
- If it is unchecked and the `filtered` array is empty, then append all items from the parent array (the one that is not filtered)

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mtx5Lg1L/2/).

Background: The checkboxes act as filters for a search and the `filtered` array stores those filtered values (in no other place other than what is in that fiddle the `filtered` array is changed yet).

My problem is that `console.log(filtered)` returns `[]` and `console.log(filtered.length)` does NOT return `0` and it should. Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

Comment: You're using `delete` to remove element from array, use `splice`.

Comment: Code goes **in** the question, not just linked.

Comment: If you wish to reply regarding the duplicate, do it as a comment, not by adding it to the question. You're right, the other question isn't really a duplicate. However, you'll get much better reception if you post relevant code immediately ***and*** make sure the code is a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that accurately reproduces the issue.

Comment: @squint To be honest, my code is only relevant if seen as a whole (I only included it in a fiddle so that it would improve readability of the question by not taking up too much space). If it is not a duplicate, can the tag be removed? Thank you for the feedback!

Comment: Here's a reduced example: https://jsfiddle.net/mtx5Lg1L/3/ All the DOM manipulation and conditionals only get in the way. If you pick things away one by one, you can get it down to something very simplified. Even my demo could be further simplified, but it conveys generally what's happening in your code at its core.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9974451/why-does-delete-keep-array-elements) is a better duplicate of yours.

Comment: @squint Ok, now I understand. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`delete` on array doesn't change the `length` of array. It just sets the element value to `undefined`. Use [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to remove element from array.