# Deleting a row from javascript object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, delete-row

I have a javascript object which looks like this :-

```
var myObject = [{"id": "1", "URL": "http://shsudhf.com", "value": "1"}, 

                {"id": "2", "URL": "http://shsusadhf.com", "value": "2"},

                {"id": "3", "URL": "http://shsudsdff.com", "value": "0"}];
```

Now , I have to delete all the rows in the object with id value `2`. How can this be done ?

Comment: you can recreate the array without the deleted part

Comment: Does it have to be a mutate operation?

Comment: What do you have handy? prototype.js? jquery?

Comment: I was using plain javascript. Recreating will be a bit slow if the number of rows are very large, I guess. Yes, it will be mutually used

Comment: Do you need the original array after you remove the items with the `id` of "2"?

Comment: @PrashantSingh Understand that mutating by removing rows from an array can be quite inefficient since in general you have to "shift" large chunks of the array.  If you can accept creating a new array, see the answer by elclanrs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't need the original array after "deleting" rows, you can use `splice` like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/rmcu5/1/

```
var myArray = [{"id": "1", "URL": "http://shsudhf.com", "value": "1"},
                {"id": "2", "URL": "http://shsusadhf.com", "value": "2"},
                {"id": "3", "URL": "http://shsudsdff.com", "value": "0"}];

function removeItemsById(arr, id) {
    var i = arr.length;
    if (i) {   // (not 0)
        while (--i) {
            var cur = arr[i];
            if (cur.id == id) {
                arr.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
    }
}

removeItemsById(myArray, "2");

console.log(JSON.stringify(myArray));
```

It doesn't create a new array, just modifies the original in place. If you need the original array and all of its items, then use one of the other solutions that return you a modified copy of the original.

Comment: +1 for splice as this is the "native" way to remove items from an array.

Comment: Can you explain a bit about arr.splice ?

Comment: @PrashantSingh It takes 3 parameters (only the first 2 we're worried about). The first parameter is the index to start removing items from, and the second parameter is how many items to remove. I just set it as `1` because we only want to remove the single item in the loop (its `id` is `2`)

Comment: @PrashantSingh The looping starts at the end of the array and loops to the beginning, which is important for something like this because you're modifying the array directly while looping through it and can throw off the looping

Comment: @PrashantSingh No problem. Just remember, this modifies the original array. If you want to keep the original array in its state but also get a copy that has specific items removed, you would need to use someone else's solution. It really depends on what you specifically need to do

Comment: I am not interested in the original array.

Answer (score 4):

Note that what you call `myObject` is actually an array therefore you can use array methods on it:

```
myObject = myObject.filter(function( obj ) {
  return obj.id != 2;
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/LXpYj/

Comment: That's very nice but the OP did ask for a mutator.  I don't agree with the OP's request for a mutator.  Your solution is obviously the best, since removing from the middle of an array is awful.  If the OP agrees that this is okay, I'll +1.

Comment: @PrashantSingh Note that this is not available on IE < 9. You'd have to include a polyfill just for the `filter` method to work on them

Comment: @Ian Ok, that means I can't use this :O

Comment: Yes but you need to add a _polyfill_ for older browsers. A polyfill is just some code that adds that functionality if is not present. There's  a 140bytes `filter` polyfill here: https://gist.github.com/1031656. Even with the polyfill the code will be shorter and more readable than most other ways of doing this.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
function deleteObject(array,id)
{
 var newObject=[]; 
  for (var o in array) {
       if(array[o].id!=id)
          newObject.push(array[o]);
    }
return newObject;
}
```

working [JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zaheerahmed/Ctt9f/)

You can do without creating new array, you need to write remove function:

```
Array.prototype.remove = function() {
    var what, a = arguments, L = a.length, ax;
    while (L && this.length) {
        what = a[--L];
        while ((ax = this.indexOf(what)) !== -1) {
            this.splice(ax, 1);
        }
    }
    return this;
};
```

[Without New Array Delete Object](http://jsfiddle.net/zaheerahmed/78Qyc/4/)

Comment: Is recreating the array is the only solution ?

Answer (score 0):

try it with filter (its an array not a object)

```
var rr = [{"id": "1", "URL": "http://shsudhf.com", "value": "1"},  {"id": "2", "URL": "http://shsusadhf.com", "value": "2"}, {"id": "3", "URL": "http://shsudsdff.com", "value": "0"}];


rr = rr.filter(function(e) {
    return e.id != 2;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Here you go, this is without recreating the array or anything.

```
 var myObject = [{"id": "1", "URL": "http://shsudhf.com", "value": "1"}, 

                {"id": "2", "URL": "http://shsusadhf.com", "value": "2"},

    {"id": "3", "URL": "http://shsudsdff.com", "value": "0"}];

for(i=0,iMax=myObject.length;i<iMax;i++){
    (function (a) { 
        if(this.id=="2"){
          delete myObject[a];
        }
    }).call(myObject[i],i);
}

console.log(myObject);
​
​
```

jsFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/gG2zz/1/

Comment: You do realize that [**THIS**](http://jsfiddle.net/gG2zz/2/) would do exactly the same, and it still would'nt remove anyting, it just sets the array items to undefined ?

Comment: @adeneo well I'm sorry if it's late and I'm tired. but why do you say it doesn't delete it [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/346021/how-do-i-remove-objects-from-a-javascript-associative-array)

Comment: delete works fine on objects, like in the linked question, but on arrays the index is not updated, and the length would still be the same, so it's not really "deleted", that's the main problem with arrays, deleting stuff is a pain in the a$$, and usually takes some slicing and dicing.