# remove an object from an object array in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object

I have an object which is like:

```
Object {w74: Object, w100: Object,w12: Object,w3: Object}
```

I need to eleminate one of them to have

```
Object {w74: Object, w100: Object,w3: Object}
```

How can remove this in javascript

Comment: `delete <Object>[<index>]` ?

Comment: Duplicate of [How do I remove objects from a javascript associative array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/346021/how-do-i-remove-objects-from-a-javascript-associative-array)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [delete operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete):

```js
var ob = {w74: {number: 1}, w100: {number: 2},w12: {number: 3},w3: {number: 4}};
console.log(ob);
delete ob.w74;
console.log(ob);
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can directly delete your value from object by key value**

eg.

```
  var arrChildOptions2 = {
       w74: Object, w100: Object,w12: Object,w3: Object
     };
```

delete arrChildOptions2.w12;

Answer (score 0):

Use underscore library function called _.pick() http://underscorejs.org/#pick

```
_.pick({name: 'moe', age: 50, userid: 'moe1'}, 'name', 'age');
=> {name: 'moe', age: 50}

_.pick({name: 'moe', age: 50, userid: 'moe1'}, function(value, key, object) {
  return _.isNumber(value);
});
=> {age: 50}
```