# Delete items from a Map based on a condition

Tags: javascript

How do I delete items from a Map based on a condition, for example:

```
m = {a:{name: "A"}, b:{name: "B"}, B:{name: "B"}, aa:{name: "A"}}
```

I wish to remove the two entries where `name==="B"`.

Can I delete in a `foreach`?

Comment: Is this an actual [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/delete)? Or is it an object like in your code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/346021/how-do-i-remove-objects-from-a-javascript-associative-array

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hhoohdnd/

Answer (score 2):

You could iterate the keys and delete accordingly

```js
var m = { a: { name: "A" }, b: { name: "B" }, B: { name: "B" }, aa: { name: "A" } };

Object.keys(m).forEach(function (k) {
    if (m[k].name === 'B') {
        delete m[k];
    }
});

console.log(m);
```