# Fastest way to get specific fields in an Object - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an object:

```
var obj = { a: 'test1', b: 'test2', c: 'test3', d: 'test4', e: 'test5', f: 'test6', g: 'test7', h: 'test8' }
```

I want to get result:

```
res = { a: 'test1', c: 'test3', d: 'test4' }
```

What is the fastest way to do it?

Comment: use `delete obj.e`

Comment: @Justcode Hmmm, you might want to test that. Particularly test accessing other properties on `obj` after you do it. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder shouldn't be a problem with if you are dealing with 1 property.

Comment: @Justcode - Again, you might want to test that. It's well-known that deleting a property blows away object optimization. Even just the one.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder you are talking about this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/742653/2630817

Comment: @Justcode - No, I'm talking about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/346022/157247) (see: https://jsperf.com/effect-of-delete-on-performance/1).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thank you, time to do some re-work :D

Comment: @Justcode :-) Of course, it's a bit micro-opt. (And that synthetic benchmark doesn't reveal the problem on Firefox; the delete right after creation gets optimized away I think.) It's just, the OP did specifically say "fastest"... ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Directly access the fields:

```
const res = {a: obj.a, c: obj.c, d: obj.d};
```

Live Example:

```js
const obj = {
    a: "test1",
    b: "test2",
    c: "test3",
    d: "test4",
    e: "test5",
    f: "test6",
    g: "test7",
    h: "test8",
};
const res = { a: obj.a, c: obj.c, d: obj.d };
console.log(JSON.stringify(res, null, 4));
```

---

In a comment, Himanshu Agrawal asked:

> What if the key is unknown and stored in a variable? const keys = ["a", "c", "d"];

I'd probably use a `for-of` loop to handle that:

```
const res = {};
for (const key of keys) {
    res[key] = obj[key];
}
```

Live Example:

```js
const obj = {
    a: "test1",
    b: "test2",
    c: "test3",
    d: "test4",
    e: "test5",
    f: "test6",
    g: "test7",
    h: "test8",
};
const keys = ["a", "b", "c"];
const res = {};
for (const key of keys) {
    res[key] = obj[key];
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(res, null, 4));
```

But you could also use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries):

```
const res = Object.fromEntries(keys.map((key) => [key, obj[key]]));
```

Live Example:

```js
const obj = {
    a: "test1",
    b: "test2",
    c: "test3",
    d: "test4",
    e: "test5",
    f: "test6",
    g: "test7",
    h: "test8",
};
const keys = ["a", "b", "c"];
const res = Object.fromEntries(keys.map((key) => [key, obj[key]]));
console.log(JSON.stringify(res, null, 4));
```

That said, the question asks for the *fastest* way to do it, and the `map`+`Object.fromEntries` approach involves several temporary object allocations and function calls. In most cases, it won't matter but the `for-of` is probably faster (depending on the degree of optimization the JavaScript engine does). Or a boring old-fashioned `for` loop might be faster still:

```
const res = {};
for (let n = 0; n < keys.length; ++n) {
    const key = keys[n];
    res[key] = obj[key];
}
```

Live Example:

```js
const obj = {
    a: "test1",
    b: "test2",
    c: "test3",
    d: "test4",
    e: "test5",
    f: "test6",
    g: "test7",
    h: "test8",
};
const res = {};
for (let n = 0; n < keys.length; ++n) {
    const key = keys[n];
    res[key] = obj[key];
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(res, null, 4));
```

Again, it's unlikely to matter, but it's good to have multiple approaches for situations where it may.

Comment: What if the key is unknown and stored in a variable? const keys = ["a", "c", "d"];

Comment: @HimanshuAgrawal - I've updated the post to answer that additional question.

Answer (score 1):

i think you want to delete `key-value` pair from the object so for that here's the solution

```
delete obj[b];

delete obj[e];
```

or you can use `lodash pick`

```
var _ = require('lodash')
_.pick( obj, [a, c, d] )
```

or create a new `Object`

```
var final = {a: obj.a, c: obj.c, d: obj.d}
```

Comment: You might want to test that. Particularly test accessing other properties on `obj` after you do it. :-) `delete` has a significant unfortunate affect on the performance of objects you apply it to.

Comment: yeah, but i've seen a lot of cases where one need to change the current variable only instead of creating a new one. That's why i've multiple methods. Anyway thanks for pointing that out. :)

Comment: Well, you didn't [when I posted that comment](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/52888187/1). And `_.pick` is certainly not going to be the "fastest" way (not even remotely).